# Do cardiologists learn nutrition as part of their expertise in Cardiology?

Tags: cardiology

Almost all physicians I recognized as suggesting medicinal nutrition either as direct therapy, preventive medicine and via "popular medicine" as with books and articles, were Cardiologists; to a lesser extent I came across endocrinologists and gastroenterologists (particularly about microbiota).

Do cardiologists learn nutrition as part of their expertise in Cardiology?

Comment: Cardiologists learn about nutrition "by the way," that is as part of a particular subject: they learn about the effect of sodium and obesity on blood pressure, cholesterol on atherosclerosis, electrolytes on hearth rhythm, excessive water drinking on heart failure, etc. There is not really much more "exact" evidence about the effects of nutrition on heart health or health in general.

Comment: Doctors read too in their spare time, if they have any. Doctors talk among themselves. They attend continuing education and so on.

Comment: @Jan wouldn't that also include empty calories of lipid liquids (many kinds of edible oils) on obesity (and thus on the heart)? I was also wondering about about Potassium and Magnesium and the heart; maybe the addition of this could help constructing an answer.

Comment: @JohnDoea, I believe cardiologists know what's important for their field: the effect of sodium, potassium, trans fat and obesity on the circulatory system. They don't need to know all nutrients that supposedly affect appetite. I also believe if a cardilogist thinks that a patient needs to follow a certain specific diet, he/she will refer to a nutritionist. It's not a cardiologist's job to plan diets to patients. As long as a cardioligst thiks a patient has roughly an adequate diet with normal blood mineral/vitamin levels, he/she may not need to bother further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

Lifestyle modification as part of non-pharmacological treatment of heart diseases are known to have significant effect on patient's health. 
Nutrition plays a large part in lifestyle modification. 
Role of food and nutrition is part of most residency training and essential reading.

There are specific competencies (entrustable professional activities) that cardiologists must attain and demonstrate for certification.

**[From the Entrustable Professional Activities for Subspecialists in Cardiovascular Disease:] by the Americal College of Cardiology : [1](https://www.acc.org/education-and-meetings/products-and-resources/competencies/table-5-cardiovascular-disease-prevention-lifelong-learning-competencies)**

*The residents must:*
**Know the principles of nutrition** and obesity assessment and management, including the roles of pharmacotherapy and bariatric surgery.

Ref: 
https://www.acc.org/education-and-meetings/products-and-resources/competencies/table-5-cardiovascular-disease-prevention-lifelong-learning-competencies

Also, see: https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/full/10.1161/cir.0000000000000563